# Rendering PDF using object/embed/iframe is not working properly

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, pdf, rotativa

I am trying to display PDF for preview using object/embed/iframe html tags, but its not working as expected.
Can someone point out what is going wrong here?

Here is my bit of code:

In HTML **_PDFPreview.cshtml**:

```
   @model byte[]

  <div style="width: 875px;">
    <object id="previewPdf" data="data:application/pdf;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(Model)" style="overflow: visible;"/>
  </div>
```

In Controller action:

```
    public ActionResult SomeActionMethod()
    {         
     // some logic to get pdfResult object
        return View("~/View/_PDFPreview.cshtml", pdfResult.BuildPdf(ControllerContext));
    }
```

Note: I am using Rotativa NuGet package for generating the PDF. The action method returns view with proper data. But in browser it ends up in getting blank screen.

Test Case: On changing object tag to iFrame it works in Chrome but not in FireFox.

I will appreciate any kind of relevant suggestions.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the fix!

**"Test Case: On changing object tag to iFrame it works in Chrome but not in FireFox."**

My bad. It was due the FF browser setting that was directly downloading the file instead of previewing. On changing the setting the issue got fixed.

[image]

Thanks.